# Opencart 2.3 Ocmod заменяет строки

Tags: php, opencart

Почему-то неправильно отрабатывает ocmod в opencart 2.3.
Итак вот что делаю в install.xml:

```
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($shipping_method['quote'] as $quote) { ?>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            <?php if($shipping_method['code'] == "onedel"):?>
                <?php echo $onedel_content;?>
            <?php endif;?>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

указываю position before (с after такой же результат), получаю в итоге в модифицированном файле мой контент, но при этом искомая строка удаляется.

Вот исходный:

```
<?php if (!$shipping_method['error']) { ?>
<?php foreach ($shipping_method['quote'] as $quote) { ?>
<div class="radio">
```

а вот после модификации:

```
<?php if (!$shipping_method['error']) { ?>

                <?php if($shipping_method['code'] == "onedel"):?>
                    <?php echo $onedel_content;?>
                <?php endif;?>

<div class="radio">
```

Не пойму почему удаляется искомая строка. Есть еще в install.xml замены с position="before", там все ок.
В доках прочел еще про параметр offset в теге add, прописывал - не помогло.
Идеи закончились...В чем причина такого поведения?
В логах extension-modification нет ошибок.

Comment: Больше никакой модификатор с этой строкой не работает?

Comment: Нет. Более того, с этим файлом shipping_method.tpl никаких изменений не происходит больше.

Comment: После добавления модификатора обновляли кеш и следом "обновить модификаторы"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не правильно написали.

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl">
  <operation>
     <search><![CDATA[<?php foreach ($shipping_method['quote'] as $quote) { ?>]]></search>
     <add position="before"><![CDATA[
         <?php if($shipping_method['code'] == "onedel"):?>
             <?php echo $onedel_content;?>
         <?php endif;?>
     ]]></add>
  </operation>
</file>
```

Синтаксис search - `<search trim="true|flase" index="0|1|2...">`

Синтаксис add - `<add position="before|after|replace" trim="true|flase" offset="0|1|2..">`

Comment: точно! оно. Спасибо огромное.